# Is there a way to get date from database and assign it to the Raddatepicker id using javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, database

I TRIED USING THIS

**document.getElementById('<%=rdpDate.ClientID %>').value.get_selectedDate() = row.StartDate**
(startdate is a row of List that I am getting from the database)
its not working and I am getting "type error" popup saying this is not a function.

I am getting StartDate as "04/03/2020" (using `Info.StartDate = reader["StartDate"].ToString();` to get date from database) from database
I want to set `<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpDate" runat="server" Width="100px"></telerik:RadDatePicker>`
as the date from database.

Please let me know the possible solution
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMlSV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var raddatepickerStartDate = $find("<%= rdpDate.ClientID %>");
raddatepickerStartDate.set_selectedDate(new Date(row.StartDate));